# Android Grade Calculator, check edit texts. how to fix?

Tags: android, android-edittext, calculator

everyone I am new to android programming, and wanted to make a weighted grade calculator that lets the user input the weight and mark and calculates the mark. I want to know the best way to check if the user has inputted anything into the edit texts because if I try to calculate with leaving some edit texts blank, my application crashes. It only works if the user inputs all 12 fields, then it will calculate the grade, however when one of the edit texts are left blank it doesnt calculate the grade, which is what I want. for example: the user inputs 4 weights and 4 marks and clicks calculate; it should calculate with leaving weight and marks 5 and 6 blank. how many more if statements needed and hot to fix? thank you. 
this is the snippet of code I have for it:

```
if( !weight6.getText().toString().equals("") || !mark6.getText().toString().equals("") ||
    !weight5.getText().toString().equals("") || !mark5.getText().toString().equals("") ||
    !weight4.getText().toString().equals("") || !mark4.getText().toString().equals("") ||
    !weight3.getText().toString().equals("") || !mark3.getText().toString().equals("")||
    !weight2.getText().toString().equals("") || !mark2.getText().toString().equals("")){  

                num1=Double.parseDouble(weight1.getText().toString());
                num2=Double.parseDouble(mark1.getText().toString());
                num3=Double.parseDouble(weight2.getText().toString());
                num4=Double.parseDouble(mark2.getText().toString());
                num5=Double.parseDouble(weight3.getText().toString());
                num6=Double.parseDouble(mark3.getText().toString());
                num7=Double.parseDouble(weight4.getText().toString());
                num8=Double.parseDouble(mark4.getText().toString());
                num9=Double.parseDouble(weight5.getText().toString());
                num10=Double.parseDouble(mark5.getText().toString());
                num11=Double.parseDouble(weight6.getText().toString());
                num12=Double.parseDouble(mark6.getText().toString());
                result5= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8+num9*num10+num11*num12)/ (num1+num3+num5+num7+num9+num11);
                result4= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8+num9*num10)/ (num1+num3+num5+num7+num9);
                result3= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8)/ (num1+num3+num5+num7);
                result2= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6)/ (num1+num3+num5);
                result1= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 )/ (num1+num3);
                result= (num1*num2)/ (num1);
                tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result)+"%");
                tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result1)+"%");
                tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result2)+"%");
                tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result3)+"%");
                tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result4)+"%");
                tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result5)+"%");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if( !"".equals(weight6.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(mark6.getText().toString())&&!"".equals(weight5.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(mark5.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(weight4.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(mark4.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(weight3.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(mark3.getText().toString())&& !"".equals(weight2.getText().toString()) && !"".equals(mark2.getText().toString())){  

                        num1=Double.parseDouble(weight1.getText().toString());
                        num2=Double.parseDouble(mark1.getText().toString());
                        num3=Double.parseDouble(weight2.getText().toString());
                        num4=Double.parseDouble(mark2.getText().toString());
                        num5=Double.parseDouble(weight3.getText().toString());
                        num6=Double.parseDouble(mark3.getText().toString());
                        num7=Double.parseDouble(weight4.getText().toString());
                        num8=Double.parseDouble(mark4.getText().toString());
                        num9=Double.parseDouble(weight5.getText().toString());
                        num10=Double.parseDouble(mark5.getText().toString());
                        num11=Double.parseDouble(weight6.getText().toString());
                        num12=Double.parseDouble(mark6.getText().toString());
                        result5= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8+num9*num10+num11*num12)/ (num1+num3+num5+num7+num9+num11);
                        result4= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8+num9*num10)/ (num1+num3+num5+num7+num9);
                        result3= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8)/ (num1+num3+num5+num7);
                        result2= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6)/ (num1+num3+num5);
                        result1= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 )/ (num1+num3);
                        result= (num1*num2)/ (num1);
                        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result)+"%");
                        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result1)+"%");
                        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result2)+"%");
                        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result3)+"%");
                        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result4)+"%");
                        tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result5)+"%");

                        }
else{
//set all =0
}
```

Comment: I believe Double.parseDouble() will throw a NumberFormatException if the string is null or blank.

Comment: and u also can give alert messge in else block commonly.. or for single alert u need to split the if conditions.

Comment: The OP wanted to do the calculation even if some of the fields are blank.

Comment: u shud give any value for that to avoid NumberFormatException. its better to give alert message if u give any value it might give wrong output..

Comment: according to ur example in question if ur using addition to calculate set all num variables=0, else if u r using multiplication set all =1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put all the tests in one expression.  Break them up.

```
if (weight1.getText().length() > 0) {
   num1 = Double.parseDouble(weight1.getText().toString());
else
   num1 = 0;
```

and do the same for each of your fields.

Although perhaps you might want to adjust it slightly.  For example if weight is blank, you might want to treat it as weight=1 rather than weight=0.

Answer (score 0):

You required multiple if-else statement and ternary operator to calculation :

```
if(weight1.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
   num1=1.0;
}else{
   num1=Double.parseDouble(weight1.getText().toString());
}
if(mark1.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num2=1.0;
}else{
    num2=Double.parseDouble(mark1.getText().toString());
}
if(weight2.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num3=1.0;
}else{
    num3=Double.parseDouble(weight2.getText().toString());
}
if(mark2.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num4=1.0;
}else{
    num4=Double.parseDouble(mark2.getText().toString());
}
if(weight3.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num5=1.0;
}else{
    num5=Double.parseDouble(weight3.getText().toString());
}
if(mark3.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num6=1.0;
}else{
    num6=Double.parseDouble(mark3.getText().toString());
}
if(weight4.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num7=1.0;
}else{
    num7=Double.parseDouble(weight4.getText().toString());
}
if(mark4.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num8=1.0;
}else{
    num8=Double.parseDouble(mark4.getText().toString());
}
if(weight5.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num9=1.0;
}else{
    num9=Double.parseDouble(weight5.getText().toString());
}
if(mark5.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num10=1.0;
}else{
    num10=Double.parseDouble(mark5.getText().toString());
}
if(weight6.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num11=1.0;
}else{
    num11=Double.parseDouble(weight6.getText().toString());
}
if(mark6.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
    num12=1.0;
}else{
    num12=Double.parseDouble(mark6.getText().toString());
}


result5= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8+num9*num10+num11*num12)/ ((num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5+num7==1.0?0.0:num7+num9==1.0?0.0:num9+num11==1.0?0.0:num11)==0.0?1.0:(num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5+num7==1.0?0.0:num7+num9==1.0?0.0:num9+num11==1.0?0.0:num11));
result4= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8+num9*num10)/ ((num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5+num7==1.0?0.0:num7+num9==1.0?0.0:num9)==0.0?1.0:(num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5+num7==1.0?0.0:num7+num9==1.0?0.0:num9));
result3= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6+num7*num8)/ ((num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5+num7==1.0?0.0:num7)==0.0?1.0:(num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5+num7==1.0?0.0:num7));
result2= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 +num5*num6)/ ((num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5)==0.0?1.0:(num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3+num5==1.0?0.0:num5));
result1= (num1*num2 + num3 *num4 )/ ((num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3)==0.0?1.0:(num1==1.0?0.0:num1+num3==1.0?0.0:num3));
result=  (num1*num2)/ (num1==0.0?1.0:num1);

tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result)+"%");
tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result1)+"%");
tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result2)+"%");
tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result3)+"%");
tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result4)+"%");
tvResult.setText(Double.toString(result5)+"%");
```

Comment: Thank you!! it works now :), however I have one more question. what do you need to add to the if statement in order to save the mark and weight inputted so when the application is closed and re-opened, all the inputted marks are present?